# Permission denied installing sudo brew node for odoo 9 on macOS Sierra

Tags: homebrew, odoo-9

Im trying to install Odoo v9 on macOS Sierra.  I got it installed under virtualenv but when I run it (odoo.py) I get a Could not execute command lessc.  I found this:

https://dedyyuristiawan.blogspot.com/2016/07/installation-odoo-on-mac-os-x-error.html

but when i try to run sudo brew ... I get this error:

```
Error : Running Homebrew as root is extremely dangerous and no longer supported.
```

I ran it without sudo but I get:

```
Error: Permission denied - usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/.github/issue_template.md
```

When I run brew doctor I get:

```
Warning: "config" scripts exist outside your system or Homebrew directories.
`./configure` scripts often look for *-config scripts to determine if
software packages are installed, and what additional flags to use when
compiling and linking.
Having additional scripts in your path can confuse software installed via
Homebrew if the config script overrides a system or Homebrew provided
script of the same name. We found the following "config" scripts:
  /Users/mars/odoo-env/bin/python-config
Warning: You have unlinked kegs in your Cellar
Leaving kegs unlinked can lead to build-trouble and cause brews that depend on
those kegs to fail to run properly once built. Run `brew link` on these:
  node
```

So I ran this:

```
(odoo-env) Marcios-MacBook-Pro:odoo mars$ brew cleanup
(odoo-env) Marcios-MacBook-Pro:odoo mars$ brew link node
Linking /usr/local/Cellar/node/7.2.0... 
Error: Could not symlink bin/node
Target /usr/local/bin/node
already exists. You may want to remove it:
  rm '/usr/local/bin/node'
To force the link and overwrite all conflicting files:
  brew link --overwrite node
To list all files that would be deleted:
  brew link --overwrite --dry-run node
(odoo-env) Marcios-MacBook-Pro:odoo mars$ brew cleanup
(odoo-env) Marcios-MacBook-Pro:odoo mars$ brew link node
Linking /usr/local/Cellar/node/7.2.0... 
Error: Could not symlink bin/node
Target /usr/local/bin/node
already exists. You may want to remove it:
  rm '/usr/local/bin/node'

To force the link and overwrite all conflicting files:
  brew link --overwrite node

To list all files that would be deleted:
  brew link --overwrite --dry-run node
```

Anyone know a workaround?

Comment: Try executing brew doctor

Comment: Ok I updated the post with the results from brew doctor

Comment: You can't, or you can, but it is not recommended, to install to /usr. You can override it. Macports install to /opt so try to change to this destination instead.

Comment: install what to /opt? Please help, Im not too familiar with this.

Comment: Official homebrew path is [`/usr/local`](https://github.com/Homebrew/brew/blob/master/docs/FAQ.md#why-does-homebrew-prefer-i-install-to-usrlocal).

Comment: Did you get this sorted @marciokoko? I just had a similar issue and managed to work it out.

Comment: I think I ended up reinstalling brew

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Execute this and youre fine:
`sudo chown -R $(whoami):admin /usr/local/lib/node_modules/`